# How change object property value typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface State {
    customerId: number,
    step: string
}

const data: State = {
    step: 'shipping',
    customerId: 123
}

const setData = (key: string, value: number) => {
    data[key] = value
}

setData('customerId', 555)
```

Im try change value of customerId but got error:
**No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'State'.**

How i can set new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition of `setData` to include a generic parameter `K`. `K` represents the key of `State` you are trying to modify. The type of `value` will be `State[K]`. This is how we can model a relation between the `key` and `value` parameter.

```
const setData = <K extends keyof State>(key: K, value: State[K]) => {
    data[key] = value
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUMg5BAVwGcwB7AW2gEkATALmRGKoCNoAafQ8iAA7NyUUAHNcAX1y4EFEOWT1McZukwoAvDl4F%20Q5AHJSAC2ACB4wz0JEylGlAbMAjACYAzFJlyFYZKQQYAAiKsjaADwA0sgQAB6QIPSkyADWEACeFDBoGJAAfAAU6RnMUVzIAG5wADbEEGp5EADaUQC6AJTh%20Tq2yhjNJW3hVbX13riBISqFhiTk1HT01sgArOsdQA)